# mysql workbench error code 1215: can't add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql

I am sure I have followed the answers seen from other posts, but my code is still wrong. I am not sure how o add in foreign keys to my table. I followed the instruction given on the tutorial website as well.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Spatuala` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Spatuala`(
    `idSpatula` INT NOT NULL,
    `ProductName` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    `Type` ENUM('Food', 'Drugs', 'Paints', 'Plaster') NOT NULL,
    `Size` VARCHAR(50),
    `Colour` VARCHAR(50),
    `Price` DECIMAL(10,2),
    `QuantityInStock` INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`idSpatula`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Order`;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Order`(
    `idOrder` INT NOT NULL,
    `RequestedTime` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `ResponsibleStaffMember` VARCHAR(100),
    `CustomerDetails` VARCHAR(300),
    PRIMARY KEY (`idOrder`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `OrderLineItem`;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `OrderLineItem`(
    `idSpatula` INT NOT NULL,
    `idOrder` INT NOT NULL,
    `Quantity` INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (`idSpatula`)
      REFERENCES `Spatula` (`idSpatula`)
      ON DELETE NO ACTION
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    FOREIGN KEY (`idOrder`)
      REFERENCES `Order` (`idOrder`)
      ON DELETE NO ACTION
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

typo on first table name and last table name use of it.

the below works.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Spatula`(
    `idSpatula` INT NOT NULL,
    `ProductName` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    `Type` ENUM('Food', 'Drugs', 'Paints', 'Plaster') NOT NULL,
    `Size` VARCHAR(50),
    `Colour` VARCHAR(50),
    `Price` DECIMAL(10,2),
    `QuantityInStock` INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`idSpatula`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Order`;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Order`(
    `idOrder` INT NOT NULL,
    `RequestedTime` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `ResponsibleStaffMember` VARCHAR(100),
    `CustomerDetails` VARCHAR(300),
    PRIMARY KEY (`idOrder`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `OrderLineItem`;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `OrderLineItem`(
    `idSpatula` INT NOT NULL,
    `idOrder` INT NOT NULL,
    `Quantity` INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (`idSpatula`)
      REFERENCES `Spatula` (`idSpatula`)
      ON DELETE NO ACTION
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    FOREIGN KEY (`idOrder`)
      REFERENCES `Order` (`idOrder`)
      ON DELETE NO ACTION
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Ideally you would just delete this question as it doesn't help anyone else later. Thx.